Editing a post and publishing simultaneously doesn't apply the edit to the published post
I edited https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78620089, and then decided that after cleaning up some repetition it was decent enough to publish so selected "Approve and post on main site" with the edit window still open. The result was that my edit was applied to the staging ground copy of the post but not the main site copy which I then had to edit manually.

The Staging Ground revision history and timeline reflect this as well: the post was published, then the edit was applied.

This was an issue during the beta and was fixed (but now, obviously, has regressed). For (potentially useful, but what do I know) internal reference, the ticket number was 918

Interestingly, I used the approve option from the edit menu a few times and my edits got applied to the published posts.

What makes it worse is that once a staging ground post has been published(?) there is no Edit link anymore which would allow copying the edited markdown to the published question (and copying from Source in the revision history inserts unwanted blank lines, at least on Windows).

Another meta question has noted that this also happens for edits by the asker.

I'd like to know if there are steps to replicate the issue. I'm trying to replicate in a dev environment by having two tabs opened, one to the edit page of a question and the other to the question itself. In the edit page tab, I enter some text. In the other tab, I press "Approve and post on main site" and then try to submit my changes in the edit tab but I am prevented from doing so even if I try to select the "Approve and post on main site" or "Save without review".

@tanj92 You should only use one tab.  Click the edit button under the question, create an edit, and then submit the edit with "Approve and post on main site" (tested on this staging-ground question, which did not publish the edits - I had to edit again on the main site).

Circumvent by submitting the edit without review, and then clicking Approve and post on main site.

Same happened to me with this post, where interestingly the tag edit I made did get applied to the published post, but not the text edit

@tanj92 to replicate just choose the SG edit option and then "approve and publish". I kind of remember you click both options in this order.

@RyanM thanks, I'm having trouble replicating on the dev environment with your instructions. 1) Opened SG post 2) Clicked edit under question 3) Added some text 4) Scrolled down to add edit summary (this should be optional but I did it anyways) 5) Click "Approve and post on main site" option 6) Press Submit 7) See the toast notification and clicked on the published link and confirmed that the changes were saved.

This might be an issue that only exists on production, but we'll pass this information along for the dev to test in their local environment. Thanks for the info.

@tanj92 the bug happens intermittently. One attempt will not necessarily replicate it. One user counted 11 occurrences in 150 published questions

@tanj92 Those steps sound right to me; feel free to grab a mod or other SG reviewer on chat if you need more help/info.  Sounds like it may be a race condition/other reason for it happening intermittently (as VLAZ notes), maybe (disclaimer: speculation) related to database replication lag, if the publish is done from a read-only replica that hasn't yet propagated the edit from the writable primary (which would explain why it doesn't happen locally, since probably the local environment only has one DB instance).

Will do, we'll look into this next sprint.

my title edit went through and body edit did not. bluntly, this is an embarrassing bug to have in prod.

A fix was deployed and should be working fine now. The issue stemmed from revisions defaulting to using a ReadOnly database. Let us know if you are still experiencing issues.
